# CV::Point_ in OpenCV implementation

Tags: c++, opencv, templates

Why does `CV::Point_` class of OpenCV have an underscore at the end but when I create an instance of this class, I don't need to use the underscore (e.g: `Point a(1,2)`)?

Comment: becasue `cv::Point_<T>` is a template, while `cv::Point` is an alias for the template `cv::Point_<int>`.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the docs Opencv provides a template for cv::Point

https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/db/d4e/classcv_1_1Point__.html

> template class cv::Point_< _Tp >
>
> Template class for 2D
>   points specified by its coordinates x and y.

When you [call the template](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/257589/An-Idiots-Guide-to-Cplusplus-Templates-Part) you are calling an actual instantiation of that class and therefore call it as such, by providing details of what particular Point function to create.

```
Point2f a(0.3f, 0.f), b(0.f, 0.4f);
Point pt = (a + b)*10.f;
cout << pt.x << ", " << pt.y << endl;
```